# css transitions to multiple elements at once

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-transitions

I had applied an animation transition to svg element

```
.taskElement>rect{
    transition: 0.15s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
}
```

but if I want to apply one style of the same animation transition to many elements, like this:

```
.projectElement>rect .taskElement>rect{
    transition: 0.15s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
}
```

it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify multiple selectors by `,`, not spaces:

```css
.projectElement>rect, .taskElement>rect{
    transition: 0.15s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
}
```